# Show Data Augmenatation by Keras flow method

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want show(plot by plt) some samples about data augmentaion by using keras ImageDataGenerator

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode = "nearset"
)

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

fnames = sorted([os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname) for fname in os.listdir(train_cats_dir)])

img_path = fnames[3]
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))

x = image.img_to_array(img) # (150, 150, 3)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape) # (1, 150, 150, 3)

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1):
    plt.figure(i)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(image.array_to_img(batch[0]))
    i += 1
    if i%4==0: break
plt.show()
```

I write my code like this and it occurs "RuntimeError: boundary mode not supported" at

```
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1):
...
```

I don't know whta is the problem..

Comment: Can you add your full stacktrace?

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna I already solved it different way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from numpy import expand_dims

img = image.load_img('../dogs_vs_cats/cats_and_dogs_small/train/cats/cat.11.jpg')
data = image.img_to_array(img)
samples = expand_dims(data, 0)

it = datagen.flow(samples, batch_size=1)
for i in range(9):
    plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    batch = it.next()
    image = batch[0].astype('uint8')
    plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```